# Mono and PostgreSQL-compliant forum engine?

Tags: c#, postgresql, mono, forum

Is there a forum project that is mono/ c# based with some agnosticism for the database backend (possibly nhibernate-based)?  I am using mono with PostgreSQL ( I [wrote](http://code.google.com/p/pgprovider/) a MembershipProvider and RoleProvider using Npgsql ) and NHibernate and I want to use a forum engine with the same technologies.

It'd be ok if the forum engine was interface-based and I had to write my own stored procedures for a concrete PostgreSQL implementation, but the only open source c# forum engine I've seen is pretty tied to SQL Server.  Is there any open source project that supports persistence ignorance that maybe I could contribute PostgreSQL implementations to?  My Google-fu may not be up to snuff.

Worse comes to worst, I could write my own, but I'd really rather not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nearforums](http://nearforums.codeplex.com/) looks like a closest match. It supports Mono out of the box, and has providers for SQL Server and MySQL - adding a third one should be much easier, since they have to have an abstraction layer in place already to be able to support two different database engines.